# Designing Android UI and Implementation Using Fireworks

Tags: user-interface, android, fireworks, stencils

I want to learn designing android UI and implementation to android apps. I found one video tutorial on the web but It seems only how to design. I don't know how to use it on apps.

[Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8pN5_ynWmI)

How can I use custom UI design on my android app ? I'm using fireworks for design. For example, simple design:

[image]

How can I use this on my app ? (I know it looks terrible but I just want to learn how to do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply creating a UI in fireworks won't be enough. You'll need to split it into multiple components, and the construct it within your app using XML or Java.

The Android developer site [has a good set](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html) of documentation and guides on doing this.

Searching on Google will also give you lots of tutorials for the different UI elements and how to style them.

Your layout will require a tabbed Activity (or an ActionBar with tabs), a TextView and a Switch, from what I can see.

Comment: If I understood true, I don't create all of component using fireworks. For example, I need one button and one TextView. First I will design my button and implement to app, second I will design TextView and implement to app. Each compenent has to be designed independently. Is it true?

Comment: @melih sort of, yes. In code, you make every component in much the same way. In Fireworks you simply design the styles for the UI, which you can then apply to the app.